# How do I show an alert in a parent view in MacOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sprite-kit

I have created a protocol called Alertable that I use on
my class GameScene: SKScene, Alertable {
I have got it to work with iOS but not MacOS

```
extension Alertable where Self: SKScene {

    func showAlert(withTitle title: String, message: String) {
        #if os(iOS) || os(tvOS)
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) { _ in }
            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
        #else // MacOS version
            let alert = NSAlert()
            alert.messageText = title
            alert.informativeText = message
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
            //alert.runModal() == .alertFirstButtonReturn
            //view?.window?.contentViewController?.present(alert)
        #endif
    }
```

Comment: Uncomment `//alert.runModal() == .alertFirstButtonReturn`

Comment: I comment it out because it dues not work because it's hidden by the SKScene view. that's why in the iOS version I have to target the rootViewController so I can see the alert. can't seem to do the same with MacOS